How to connect Azure Function to a local SQL Server
Here is the connection string:
"connectionStringSetting": "Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=EVCS_DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

I tried running the functions but I got this error:

Sending exception event: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)


If you give azure a localhost server, do you mean you local computer? Think about how it could possibly find your computer
